# Unable to Consume Web-service in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I am trying consume a webservice hosted by

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

but eclipse showing "The service defintion selected is invalid"

[image]

**I did check the followings:**

1.opened the above wsdl url in ie and xml displayed properly

2.eclipse have network connectivity,it shows list of update when help-->check for update is clicked

3.Downloaded a copy of the wsdl and was able to generate client components.But when i tried to invoke a method i am getting connection refused error

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by a correct proxy in JVM arguments.The problem was as i was under a corporate proxy firewall,My java was failing to retreive the wsdl from the external link.Hope it helps to somebody who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

Tomcat is running under the server tab during your are doing this step.

choose the right Apache axis under Web service client in the configuration.